# Switching Databases in LocalHost

Tags: database, mysql, wp-config

3 weeks ago I uploaded all my files from localhost to cPanel. I want to switch it back , the issue I facing is my original database from the localhost is not updated . I downloaded the database from the cPanel and tried to set it in local host in wp-config.php , but its transferring me to installation every time and then resetting all the data. How can I update the database so it will show the site the same exact way as in production?

Answer (score 0):

just to understand you...
You have a livesite on some host which uses cpanel and you want to revert it back to your local Installation? (e.g. xamp)

I think the easiest way is to use a Backup/Restore plugin. For example Akeeba Backup (free and easy to use). It also helps you to replace permalinks that may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the installation page, it means that you probably have:

1. Incorrect database name in `wp-config.php` - Look for `DB_NAME` in the file. It should match the database name used when you imported it to localhost
2. Incorrect database table prefix in `wp-config.php`. Check if `$table_prefix` is the same on production and on your local

Note: I'm assuming that you already downloaded the database from cPanel and imported it into localhost. You can read the [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) page on the Codex. Don't forget to update the `siteurl` and `home` fields in the `options` table, else you'll be redirected to the production server.